# How to update Android Studio in Linux mint? Error: Studio does not have write access to /app/extra. Please run it by a privileged user to update

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]
Update & Restart button is disable.

> Error: Studio does not have write access to /app/extra. Please run it
>   by a privileged user to update.

Can some one please give a solution for updating the latest Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: Do you have write access to the directory? Have you tried running it with sudo? Could the software be upgraded via package manager such as apt?

Answer (score 5):

Try running this line in the terminal:

```
$ flatpak update
```

Worked for me (LinuxMint 19.1)

Comment: Worked for me too